# Why does the local variable throw a NPE with Jooq and JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, jooq

Coding away like usual on my JavaFX and Jooq project, I noticed this interesting behavior:

```
private JooqRecord foo;

@FXML
private Label bar;

public void loadFoo(JooqRecord r) {

        this.foo = r;

        this.bar.setText(r.getBar()); // This is null
}
```

This code will throw a NullPointerException, but if I do this:

```
private JooqRecord foo;

@FXML
private Label bar;

public void loadFoo(JooqRecord r) {

        this.foo = r;

        this.bar.setText(foo.getBar()); // Works as intended
}
```

It works exactly as intended.

If I print `r` to console after the assignment to the global variable, it will print the record just fine.

**Why does this happen?**

Comment: Multithreaded use of JavaFX? I would guess you got a race conditition: Sometimes the FXML has been loaded and ' bar` has been injected by FXML and sometimes not.

Comment: I find this pretty hard to believe; can you create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). What is `null` when you get the `NullPointerException`, `r`, or `bar`?

Comment: I'm not sure I can create a MCVE, but I didn't really want to believe it either. I had this issue for 2h before I tried just changing the variable from local to the global. I might have to add that I am also using the Jooq generated code classes for the POJOs.

Comment: @James_D I find this hella close to an MCVE, personally.